# PowerShell - Get Password Expiration for all non Disabled Users in AD

Tags: powershell, passwords

My goal is to create a single object in powershell that shows the AD display name and password expiration date for all non-disabled users.
This is relatively easy. However, the date is retrieved in an unreadable format so I convert the date.

Creating the two variables that contain the data I want is working.
The problem is when I try to combine those two variables I get a single object with two headers as expected but the two columns below are empty.

I'm using PowerShell V2 on Win 7 Pro SP1

Any ideas what the issue could be?

```
# Get users DisplayName and password expiration time from AD
$msdsComputed = Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq  $False} -Properties "DisplayName", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" |  
        Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -ne $null} 

# Convert date to human readable format
$ExpiryDate = $msdsComputed | Foreach-Object {
             ([datetime]::FromFileTime(($_)."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")) 
                          } | Select-Object "DateTime"



$combined = @{            
              DisplayName   = $msdsComputed.DisplayName
              ExpiryDate    = $ExpiryDate.DateTime
             }
New-Object PSObject -Property $combined | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a revised version of your script without looping issues:

```
$reportObject = @()
$userList = Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq  $False} -Properties "DisplayName", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" |  Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -ne $null}
$userList | %{

    $output = "" | Select DisplayName, ExpiryDate
    $output.DisplayName = $_.DisplayName
    $output.ExpiryDate = ([datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")).DateTime
    $reportObject += $output
    #Next 2 Lines provide debugging... I'm not sure the date time portion will work without having AD to play with
    $output | fl *
    ([datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")).DateTime 
}

$reportObject | Convertto-CSV -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At line:8 char:21
+     $reportObject += <<<<  $output
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: Sorry I dropped the $ on $reportObject = @()

Comment: One liner equivalent: Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq  $False} -Properties "DisplayName", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" |  Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -ne $null} | Select DisplayName,@{Name="ExpiryDate";Expression={([datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")).DateTime}} | Convertto-CSV -NoTypeInformation

Comment: I would give you 100 upvotes but I don't have enough reputation points to upvote...