# PowerShell Get-ADUser password expiration is giving the wrong date

Tags: powershell

I have the following command executed in PowerShell:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity dummyUser -Properties *
```

When I check the AccountExpirationDate it is giving tomorrow's date whereas it was set to Yesterday date. How can I get the exact date?

Comment: can you try using `Get-ADUser -identity name –Properties "DisplayName", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" |
Select-Object -Property "Displayname",@{Name="ExpiryDate";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}}
` trying this on a few accounts i'm getting accurate information

Comment: Got this error `Cannot find an object with identity: 'name'`

Comment: Well yes, you should change `name` to the ad account name you're attempting to get the information on - if you want to pull all accounts which will expire use `Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False} –Properties "DisplayName", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" |
Select-Object -Property "Displayname",@{Name="ExpiryDate";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}}`

Comment: Well this give me completely different date

Comment: Gives me 3 months date :-O

Comment: Just to clarify are you referring to when the account itself expires or the password expires?

Comment: In chat I posted

Comment: **Related**: [Get Password Expiration for all non Disabled Users in AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567165/powershell-get-password-expiration-for-all-non-disabled-users-in-ad)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for password and account expiration

To identify password expiration you can use the following for a particular user:

```
Get-ADUser -identity name –Properties "DisplayName", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" |
Select-Object -Property "Displayname",@{Name="ExpiryDate";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}}
```

Another option which allows you to target everyone within your AD:

```
Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False} –Properties "DisplayName", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" | 
Select-Object -Property "Displayname",@{Name="ExpiryDate";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}}
```

With regards to identifying an AD account expiration date:

```
get-aduser -identity mame -properties AccountExpirationDate,accountExpires | select samaccountname, `
@{Name="AccountExpirationDate";Expression={([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.AccountExpirationDate))}},`
@{Name="accountExpires";Expression={([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.accountExpires))}}
```

Do note, however, if the account is set to never expire your output will look similar to:

```
samaccountname AccountExpirationDate accountExpires
-------------- --------------------- --------------
name           01/01/1601 00:00:00
```

Comment: Note that you shouldn't need to convert AccountExpirationDate. That's a computed property that was added to Get-ADUser that takes the accountExpires property and converts it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have [Fine-Grained Password Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/get-started/adac/introduction-to-active-directory-administrative-center-enhancements--level-100-#fine_grained_pswd_policy_mgmt) enabled.

To get the get the Active Directory fine-grained password policy, use:

- [`Get-ADFineGrainedPasswordPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adfinegrainedpasswordpolicy?view=win10-ps)

To get the resultant password policy for a user, use:

- [`Get-ADUserResultantPasswordPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduserresultantpasswordpolicy?view=win10-ps)